# Incorrect data read from XML to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, xml

I have an XML File with the below structure:

```
   <tickets>
       <ticket id='TKT*****'>
      <description>blah blah </description>
      <area>pdk</area>
      <severity>aaaaaaa</severity>
      <type>Defect</type>
      <tech>aaaaaaaa</tech>
      <part>aaaaaaa</part>
      <state>Closed</state>
      <disposition>aaaaaaaa</disposition>
      <flavor>aaaaaa</flavor>
      <link>pdm</link>
      <vendor>TSMC</vendor>
      <date>2010-06-09</date>
      </ticket>
</tickets>
```

I am trying into load it into a MySQL table using HiediSQL. I created a temp table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE(
    `id` VARCHAR(20),
`description` TEXT,
`area` TEXT , 
`severity` TEXT  ,
`type` TEXT , 
`tech` TEXT  ,
`part` TEXT , 
`state` TEXT  ,
`disposition` TEXT ,
`flavor` TEXT ,
`link` TEXT  ,
`vendor` TEXT ,
`date` DATE  ,
`assign` DATE ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

 LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\nxf33836\Downloads\pdm\pdm_open_2011-02-14.xml'
 INTO TABLE TEST_TABLE ;
```

The rows are not getting identified and everything gets filled in Column 1 as shown in the below pic, I tried using :

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/pdm_open_2011-02-14.xml'
 INTO TABLE TEST_TABLE(id,description,area,severity,type,tech,part,state,disposition,flavor,link,vendor,date,assign)
 ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<ticket>' ;
```

But it gives a syntax error. I also tried

```
  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/pdm_open_2011-02-14.xml'
 INTO TABLE TEST_TABLE(id,description,area,severity,type,tech,part,state,disposition,flavor,link,vendor,date,assign)
    ROWS IDENTIFIED BY 'ticket' ;
```

[image]

What am I missing here ?

Comment: You need to escape all the backslashes, or use forward slashes.

Comment: I get this error :SQL Error (2): File 'C:\Users\nxf33836\Downloads\pdm\pdm_open_2011-02-14.xml' not found (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Comment: Then you're not giving the correct pathname.

Comment: Thanks, I got the file path corrected and I get this error now, how do I correct this?

Comment: You changed from `LOAD XML` to `LOAD DATA`. That for CSV files, not XML.